# How to get the value of subnet ref using azure cli based on a subnet name

Tags: azure

I want to put the value of the subnet id of a subnet name i provide in a variable. I run the command below and it shows the id and all the other details for the subnet

```
az network vnet subnet show -g vnetrg01 -n subnet01 --vnet-name vnet01
```

So i used the below to place the ref in a variable but it doesnt work?

```
$subnetref = az network vnet subnet show -g vnetrg01 -n subnet01 --vnet-name vnet01 --query "[].id" -o tsv
```

Comment: which language are we talking about? Powershell? bash?

Comment: im using the powershell azurecli

Comment: and what does "not working" mean? do you get any error message?

Answer (score 3):

Below worked for me to get subnet id.

```
SUBNET=$(az network vnet subnet list --subscription test-subscription --resource-group test-RG --vnet-name test-vnet --query "[?name=='test-subnet'].id" --output tsv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out the solution:

```
$subnetref = az network vnet subnet list --resource-group vnetrg01 --vnet-name vnet01 --query "[?name=='SUBNET01'].id"
```